# Xamarin Converter Not Called

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, converters

The converter inside the stacklayout is not been called untill i change the binding during runtime.
During runtime i delete the "." in the code line                                                             
then rewrite it , which makes the converter to be called.

It seems the binding not working thus not calling the converter.

code:

```
                   <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
                                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid >
                                                    <ScrollView>
                                                        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding List2}" >
                                                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <Frame >
                                                                        <Image Source="{Binding ., Converter={x:StaticResource DownloadImageConverter}}" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                                                                    </Frame>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </ScrollView>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate >
                                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean  by  words `untill i change the binding during runtime`  .  Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: What exactly do you have in your "List"

Comment: please show the XAML where you declare your converter

Comment: thank your for your time,  but the problem was in the binding. The image control didn't know what items to bind to, items of List2 (StackLayout) or items in List1(CollectionView).  The issue was resolved by adding relativesource to the binding of image control to let it know which item to bind to and its Type . " Source={ RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models: --ModelType-- }, AncestorLevel=1 } . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings